# Angular 2 - Criação de Componentes (Tags)

Tags: php, javascript, jsf, angular

Como faço para criar componentes no Angular? Quero que minha equipe coloque uma TAG Ex:

```
<campoBusca></campoBusca>
```

e na tela já seja impresso um *input* todo certinho, com as *divs* necessárias, etc! deu pra entender? É o mesmo principio do componente do JSF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Crie um componente (campo-busca.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'my-campo-busca',

  templateUrl: './campo-busca.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./campo-busca.component.css']

})

export class CampoBuscaComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

2- Defina o html do componente (campo-busca.component.html)

```
<input type="text"...
```

3- Declare o componente no módulo da aplicação (app.module.ts)

```
import { CampoBuscaComponent } from 'campo-busca.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CampoBuscaComponent ]
})
```

4- Use no html:

```
<my-campo-busca></my-campo-busca>
```

Como boa prática deve-se usar o prefixo my, para distinguir dos componentes nativos do angular.

Vale a pena dar uma olhada na [convenção de nomenclatura e estatura do angular](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)

*Tenho um código em angular 4 no github que uso com angular cli.

Se quiser pode clonar e analisar o código. Só precisa instalar o angular cli antes com o comando:

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

E depois `ng serve --open` para abrir

https://github.com/Marcelo-Rodrigues/ng-architect