# Incluir componentes em partes diferentes da pagina

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Suponhamos que eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>

<form>
</form>
```

As páginas que herdarem este template irá definir quais linhas e colunas terão minhas tabelas, quais serão os campos do formulário e quais serão os botões.

Tenho diferentes áreas de meu template que precisam ser preenchidas. Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondi uma dúvida semelhante no post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246370/94387

**Complementando:**

Se você quiser passar parâmetros para o componente insira no campo-busca.componente.ts:

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-campo-busca',
   templateUrl: './campo-busca.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./campo-busca.component.css']
 }) 

export class CampoBuscaComponent { 
    @Input nome: string;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Use o parâmetro injetado no template do componente (campo-busca.component.html):

```
<input type="text" [value]="nome">
```

Para consumir o componente utilize a tag definida no selector e forneça os parâmetros como atributos.

Exemplo fornecendo string:

```
<my-campo-busca nome="nome string fixa" ></my-campo-busca>
```

Exemplo fornecendo uma variável:

```
<my-campo-busca [nome] ="variavel" ></my-campo-busca>
```

Se você quiser definir templates injetados no seu componente. Por Ex:

```
<my-painel-leitura>
   <ng-container titulo>
   ‎   <h1>Título</h1>
   ‎</ng-content>
   ‎<ng-container conteudo>
   ‎   Conteúdo! 
   ‎</ng-content>
</my-painel-leitura>
```

Leia sobre transclusion:
https://www.google.com.br/amp/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content